# How to address the Error argument of length 0

Tags: r

```
library(drought)
thre=-0.8
Res <- RunDS(z, thre)

Month Year   z
1     2021  0.8
2     2021  1.2
3     2021  1.3
4     2021  1.4
5     2021  1.8
6     2021  2.1
7     2021  2.5
8     2021  2.9
9     2021  1.7
10    2021  1.5
11    2021  0.8
12    2021  0.5
```

If the results have no value lower than the threshold, it is giving an error

```
Error in st[i]:ed[i] : argument of length 0
```

I want that if it's 0, then it simply writes 0 in the results columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is something that's solvable inside the `RunDS()` function.  However, you could write a function that wraps `RunDS()` such that it handles the relevant errors in the way you want.  In the function below, if the function produces an error and part of the error is `"length 0"`, then it simply returns a one-row matrix where Duration and Severity are both 0.  If the error is some other kind, it returns an error.  If there is no error, it returns the result from `RunDS()`.

```r
library(drought)
dat <- structure(list(Month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
), Year = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021), z = c(0.8, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.8, 2.1, 2.5, 2.9, 
1.7, 1.5, 0.8, 0.5)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
myRunDS <- function(...){
  out <- try(drought::RunDS(...))
  if(inherits(out, "try-error")){
    if(grepl("length 0", out)){
      out <- matrix(c(0,0), ncol=2)
      colnames(out) <- c("Duration", "Severity")
      rownames(out) <- 1
    }else{
      stop("Error not regarding length 0 vector.\n")
    }
  }
  return(out)
}
```

Here's the result of the length=0 error.  Note, the error message is printed, but it's the matrix that is returned from the function.

```r
myRunDS(matrix(dat$z, ncol=1), -.1)
#> Error in st[i]:ed[i] : argument of length 0
#>   Duration Severity
#> 1        0        0
```

Here's what happens if there is no error.

```r
myRunDS(matrix(dat$z, ncol=1), 1)
#>   Duration Severity
#> 1        1      0.2
#> 2        2      0.7
```

Here's what happens when the error is something other than a length 0 vector error.

```r
myRunDS(matrix(dat$z, ncol=2), 1)
#> Error in DI[st[i]:ed[i], 1] : subscript out of bounds
#> Error in myRunDS(matrix(dat$z, ncol = 2), 1): Error not regarding length 0 vector.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much. It has been working perfectly. How can I transfer this output to CSV form, please?

Comment: You could do `out <- myRunDS(matrix(dat$z, ncol=1), 1)` and then `write.csv(out, file="result.csv")` that will produce a .csv of the resulting matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been looking for help for days but you have solved it in a few mins. Thanks so much